# Array object filtration and different sequences for Card Game

Tags: javascript

**Game Rules:**

The Deck contains `54*2 = 108 Cards`.

Note: 2 types of joker are there in the game.

- Common Joker
- A dynamically generated joker which can be of any card value.

While submitting the cards, the proper submit will be treated when

1. There are 4 groups with 13 cards in total (taken care of)
2. Only 1 group can contain 4 cards. Rest, 3 cards each (taken care of)
3. 1 group must have a `pure sequence` . `Example: Ace, 2, 3 or J,Q,K,Ace or 3,4,5 (SAME SUITS)`
4. Another group must have a sequence. It can be `pure or impure`.
   `Example (Impure): Ace,2,Joker,4 or 5,6,Joker,8`
5. Rest 2 groups can contain sequences `(pure or impure)`, OR can contain same value cards of different suits `(with or without joker)`.

`Example: 2(spades), 2(clubs), joker, 2(hearts) or 3(clubs), 3(hearts), 3(spades)`

This is an attempt which has been made so far.

```js
var joker = 3; // dynamic joker card value

function getSummary(cards){
 const isJoker = c => c.value===joker || c.suit ==="joker";
 const getSortVal = c=> isJoker(c) ? 100 : c.value;
 cards.sort((c1,c2)=> getSortVal(c1)-getSortVal(c2)); //sort cards by their value  
  let jokerCount = 0,jokersUsed =0, res;  
  for(let i = cards.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) //start from end to handle jokers first (note this is assuming they will also have the larger value of 20)
  {    
      if(isJoker(cards[i])){
       jokerCount++; //handle jokers separately
       // console.log("used joker");
   } else {
       let {suit,value:val} = cards[i]; //destructure suit and value properties into variables
       if(res===undefined){ //first non joker card -> init values
         res = {uniqueSuit: suit, startOfSequence: val}; 
          if(jokerCount) res.jokersUsed =true;          
        }
        else {
         if(suit !== res.uniqueSuit) //check if there are more suits
          delete res.uniqueSuit; //no unique suit -> remove the property (alternative: set the prop to 'none')

          if(res.startOfSequence && --res.startOfSequence != val){ //check if the sequence is intact           
           if(val === 1 && i === 0 && res.startOfSequence ===10) //Ace
             res.startOfSequence++; //Ace is used as 14
           else {
             let gap = res.startOfSequence - val;              
              if(gap > 0 &&jokerCount >= gap){ //if enough jokers remaining, use them (sequence still intact)
                jokerCount-=gap;
                jokersUsed+=gap;
                res.startOfSequence=val;
              }
              else
                delete res.startOfSequence; //no sequence -> remove property from res
            }
          }
       }
     }
  }
  
  if(res === undefined){
     //only jokers (is this possible?) -> create sequence or matching values
     res={};
      //loop through suits or do what's needed to create best score
      return res;
  }
  
  if(res.startOfSequence) //Sequence found => all cards handled => return result
   return res;
  
  if(jokersUsed)   //jokers were used for sequence, but sequence was not complete
      jokerCount += jokersUsed; //reclaim jokers
      
      const addSameValue = (suit,val)=>{ //helper function to add cards of same value to collection
  if(!res.sameValues)res.sameValues = {};    
    res.sameValues[val] = (res.sameValues[val] | 1) +1; //offset always 1 because adding is done from prev. value
  };
  
  //search for same values
  let prev, cnt =cards.length - jokerCount;
  for(let i=0 ; i < cnt ; i++){
    let val = cards[i].value;
      if(prev == val)
       addSameValue(cards[i].suit,val);
      else
       prev = val;
  }

  if(jokerCount){
     //use for highest value or add to existing sequences?
      //for example, add to highest value: (might want to check for unused suits)
      addSameValue('joker', cards[cards.length-jokerCount].value);    
  }  
 

  return JSON.stringify(res);
}



var arr4 = [{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"}];
var arr5 = [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"diams"},{"value":3,"suit":"diams"},{"value":5,"suit":"spades"}];
var arr6 = [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];
var arr7 = [{"value":4,"suit":"diams"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":20,"suit":"joker"}];
 


for(let arr of [arr4,arr5,arr6,arr7]) 
  console.log(getSummary(arr)); //test output
```

It's returning objects and adding properties based on how the card groups are arranged.

The proper grouping would be

*Pure Sequence (3 or 4 cards) - Pure Sequence or Impure Sequence(3 or 4 cards) - Pure Sequence or Impure Sequence or Same value cards (3 or 4 cards) - Pure Sequence or Impure Sequence or Same value cards (3 or 4 cards)*

It doesn't have to be in that order. Just have to look for their presence.

A pure sequence cannot contain any kind of joker.

However, there are few problems with the code above.

**For Sequence Cards** - Example: [2(spades),3(spades),4(spades)]

1. For `arr4` it's saying that `jokersUsed: true` by considering 3 (dynamically set as joker) as joker even if the array is already in pure sequence. It will create problems later while recognizing which one is `pure or impure sequence`. 3 could have been considered as joker if it had a different suit or it was not a part of a sequence.

So, for cards like `[ 2(spades), 5(spades), 3 (spades), 4(spades) ]`, it should always be considered as pure sequence even if 3 is a joker dynamically generated. Here it's considering 3 as joker and adding `jokerUsed` property.

It could have considered it as joker if it were `[ 2(spades), 5(spades), 3 (clubs), 4(spades) ]` or `[ 7(spades), 8(spades), 3 (spades or clubs or whatever), 10(spades) ]`

**For Same Value Cards** - Example: [2(spades),2(clubs),2(hearts)]

2. Here in the code, it's only looking for same value cards regardless of their suits. That means, all the cards should be of different suits.
3. For same value cards searching, if there are 3 same value cards then count is coming to be 4 (not 3) and for 4 same value cards, count is coming to be 6 (not 4). So, the count should be equal to the number of same value cards.
4. Joker (normal and dynamic) is not considered here. [ `2(spades), 2(clubs), joker(static or dynamic), 2(diams)` ]. We can consider joker as `2(hearts)` here, which is not happening.

How can I implement the above 4 conditions in my code? Hope I made it clear, otherwise I'll explain again.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od7g7u9c/4/) if you want to work on..

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: `However, there are few problems with the logic.` The 4 points I mentioned in the end. It should be considered.

Comment: Can multiple criteria be met by a single group? For example, can both of requirements 3 and 4 be simultaneously met with the single group [2(spades), 3(spades), 4(spades), 5(spades)] or do they need to be met with separate groups?

Comment: The requirement 2,3 and 4 are for same value cards group. That means they are for groups containing [2(spades), 2(clubs), 2(diams), 2(hearts)]. Obviously 2(clubs) for example can be replaced with a joker card. But each of them must have a different suit.

Comment: @Ouroborus I've updated the question bottom. Please check.

Comment: If this is a standard deck, there's one of each suit for each value. I think this means problem 4 solves itself. If a set of selected cards have the same value, they will always have different suits. If the joker is being a stand-in, it can be assumed that it's a stand-in for a suit not already represented in the group; what it's a stand-in for doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not a standard deck. It's standard deck*2 . That's 108 cards with 4 standard jokers.

Comment: `getSummary()` is basically validating a provided group of cards against these rules?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It's creating an object and adding properties based on validation. And it's not validating the last 4 conditions. Apart from that, everything is working fine. Run the snippet by changing values in arrays. You will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, [here's what I have](https://jsfiddle.net/775n7802/9/). It may not entirely be complete (the aggregation of multiple groups isn't in here), but it puts the bulk of the checks in place and may give you a better idea for structure. It also expects that there are no extra cards: no submitting 4 cards for a 3-card group.

Mainly it involves breaking the rules up into the particular structures they want, building functions for each. Then we wrap it up in a rules aggregation function `getSummary()`.

```js
// Ace spades: {"value":1, suit:"spades"}
// King diamonds: {"value":12, suit:"diams"}
// Joker: {"suit":"joker"}

// In addition to the regular jokers, cards with a certain value can also behave as jokers.
// Purity of the group is only removed if a card in the group was used as a joker
var jokerValue;

// check that values match and suits are unique
function isSameValue(cards){
  var suits = ["clubs","hearts","spades","diams"];
  var jokers = [];
  var remainder = [];
  cards.forEach(function(card){
    (card.suit === "joker" ? jokers : remainder).push(card);
  });
  var pure = jokers.length === 0;
  var value;
  var matched = remainder.every(function(card){
    if(value) {
      if(value != card.value) {
        return false;
      }
      var suit = suits.indexOf(card.suit);
      if(suit < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      suits.splice(suit,1);
      return true;
    }
    value = card.value;
    return true;
  });
  // if the non-wildcards matched, just assume any wildcards are also matches,
  // otherwise, pull the fake jokers and try again
  if(matched) {
    return {isPure: pure, isSameValue: matched};
  }

  // move the fake jokers to the joker pile
  remainder = remainder.filter(function(card){
    if(card.value == jokerValue) {
      jokers.push(card);
      return false;
    }
        return true;
  });
  // reset 
  suits = ["clubs","hearts","spades","diams"];
  pure = jokers.length === 0;
  value = undefined;
  matched = remainder.every(function(card){
    if(value) {
      if(value != card.value) {
        return false;
      }
      var suit = suits.indexOf(card.suit);
      if(suit < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      suits.splice(suit,1);
      return true;
    }
    value = card.value;
    return true;
  });

  return {isPure: pure, isSameValue: matched};
}

// check that suits match; values are unchecked
function isSameSuit(cards){
  var jokers = [];
  var remainder = [];
  cards.forEach(function(card){
    (card.suit === "joker" ? jokers : remainder).push(card);
  });
  var pure = jokers.length === 0;
  var suit;
  var sameSuit = remainder.every(function(card){
    if(!suit){
      suit = card.suit;
      return true;
    }
    return card.suit == suit;
  });

    if(sameSuit) {
    return {isPure: pure, isSameSuit: sameSuit};
  }

  // pull the fake jokers and try again
  remainder = remainder.filter(function(card){
    if(card.value == jokerValue) {
      jokers.push(card);
      return false;
    }
  });

  pure = jokers.length === 0;
  suit = undefined;
  sameSuit = remainder.every(function(card){
    if(!suit){
      suit = card.suit;
      return true;
    }
    return card.suit == suit;
  });

  return {isPure: pure, isSameSuit: sameSuit};
}

// check for sequence; suits must match
function isSequence(cards){
  var sameSuit = isSameSuit(cards);
  if(!sameSuit.isSameSuit) {
    return false;
  }

  var jokers = [];
  var sequence = cards.filter(function(card){
    if(card.suit === "joker") {
      jokers.push(card);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  var pure = jokers.length === 0;

  // Sort the non-jokers
  sequence = sequence.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.value - b.value;
  });

  // skip this step is isSameSuit() reported !isPure because we know we had to 
  // use jokers so we can assume fake jokers are okay to use
  if(pure && sameSuit.isPure){
    // find a sequence
    // rotate through each card to start and count through them, filling in with available jokers as necessary
    for(var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
      var jokerCount = jokers.length;
      var lastValue = sequence[0].value;
      var fail = false;
      for(var j = 1; j < sequence.length; j++){
        if(lastValue + 1 == sequence[j].value) {
          ++lastValue;
          continue;
        }
        if(lastValue == 12 && sequence[j].value == 1) {
          lastValue = 1;
          continue;
        }
        if(jokerCount > 0) {
          jokerCount--;
          j--;
          lastValue++;
          if(lastValue > 12) {
            lastValue = 1;
          }
          continue;
        }
        fail = true;
        break;
      }
      // Did we make it through a complete sequence?
      if(!fail){
        return {isPure: pure, isSequence: !fail };
      }
      // move bottom card to top and try again
      sequence.unshift(sequence.pop());
    }
  }

  var sequence = sequence.filter(function(card){
    if(card.value == jokerValue) {
      jokers.push(card);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  pure = jokers.length === 0;

  // already sorted from earlier; try again
  for(var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
    var jokerCount = jokers.length;
    var lastValue = sequence[0].value;
    var fail = false;
    for(var j = 1; j < sequence.length; j++){
      if(lastValue + 1 == sequence[j].value) {
        ++lastValue;
        continue;
      }
      if(lastValue == 12 && sequence[j].value == 1) {
        lastValue = 1;
        continue;
      }
      if(jokerCount > 0) {
        jokerCount--;
        j--;
        lastValue++;
        if(lastValue > 12) {
          lastValue = 1;
        }
        continue;
      }
      fail = true;
      break;
    }
    if(!fail) {
      return {isPure: pure, isSequence: !fail};
    }
  }

  return {isPure: undefined, isSequence: false};
}

function getSummary(cards){
  if(cards.length != 3 && cards.length != 4) {
    // invalid number of cards, return undefined
    return;
  }

  var long = cards.length == 4;
  var sameValue = isSameValue(cards);
  var sequence = isSequence(cards);
  var pure = (sameValue.isSameValue && sameValue.isPure) || (sequence.isSequence && sequence.isPure);

  return JSON.stringify({
    "isLong": long, 
    "isPure": pure, 
    "isSameValue": sameValue.isSameValue, 
    "isSequence": sequence.isSequence
  });
}

function toString(cards) {
    var results = [];
  cards.forEach(function(card){
    if(card.suit === "joker") {
      results.push("JK");
    }
    else {
      var value;
      switch (card.value) {
        case  1: value = "A"; break;
        case 10: value = "J"; break;
        case 11: value = "Q"; break;
        case 12: value = "K"; break;
        default:
          value = card.value;
          break;
      }
      results.push(value+card.suit.charAt(0));
    }
  });
  return results.join(' ');
}

jokerValue = 3;
for(var arr of [
  [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"diams"},{"value":5,"suit":"clubs"},{"value":5,"suit":"spades"}],
  [{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"suit":"joker"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"}],
  [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"diams"},{"value":3,"suit":"diams"},{"value":5,"suit":"spades"}],
  [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"diams"},{"value":5,"suit":"spades"}],
  [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"diams"},{"value":10,"suit":"spades"}],
  [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"diams"},{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"}],
  [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"diams"}]
]) {
  console.log(toString(arr) + " " + getSummary(arr)); //test output
}
```

Comment: Good one, but you didn't consider the dynamic joker here, which was creating the main problem. Plus, the value of Ace is 1 here. If the cards are like Ace,2,3 then it's a sequence and also if cards are like J,Q,K,Ace or Q,K,Ace then also it's a sequence. Ace will then act as value 14 card. I mentioned in point number 3 on the top of the question.

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti Jokers are working as intended, acting as fills for missing cards. So are Aces; the algorithm loops back around to Ace/1 when it gets to King/12. Did you have an example where they aren't working correctly?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vukw6oj3/ Check. In the 2nd array, I replaced 4 with a joker.  It's showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined(…)`

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti Minor error, fixed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/775n7802/4/). I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @quroborus ok. But I have a confusion regarding the dynamic joker. You only considered the normal joker by checking the `suit == "joker"`. In case of dynamic joker it's a different story. The dynamic joker was the part where I got stucked the most.

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti What makes this "dynamic joker" different from a wildcard?

Comment: @quroborus . Here's how. Suppose, "dynamic joker" is a card of value 3. That makes all the cards of value 3 I have got in my hand as a wildcard. Now, consider a sequence `Ace(hearts), 2(hearts), 3(hearts)`. It's a pure sequence. But in my code above, `3(hearts)` was getting considered as a wildcard, making it an impure sequence. If the sequence was `Ace(hearts), 2(hearts), 3(spades)`, then it would have been considered as an impure one. Hope you get it.

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti So jokers are to be treated as a specific value of any suit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129741/discussion-between-sagnik-chakraborti-and-ouroborus).